# Tooltip CSS For Highlighted Dates On UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have used JQuery UI Datepicker To show/Highlight Holiday Dates of a particular Month along with Holiday Name Shown as tooltip on hovering on Holiday Date.Everything is working perfectly.

I have added tooltip to particular dates using following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dates = ['22/01/2012', '23/01/2012']; //
        //tips are optional but good to have
  var tips  = ['some description','some other description'];      

  $('#datepicker').datepicker({                
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
  });

  function highlightDays(date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        if (new Date(dates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {              
            return [true, 'gazettedHoliday', tips[i]];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
  } 

 });
</script>
```

But I cannot Add JQuery UI ToolTip Css/Custom CSS To Tooltip Text Added for Holiday Date.

How can I Add A custom CSS/JQueryUI tooltip to Above tooltip text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed that it just add title tag to the Particular holiday date cell (table td) element,

[image]

so I just added following CSS and it worked :)

```
  .gazettedHoliday {
    background: red;
    position: relative;
  }
    .gazettedHoliday a {
        background: red !important;
        color: white !important;
     }

   .gazettedHoliday:hover:after {
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    left: 20%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    min-width: 150px;
    width: auto;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

   .gazettedHoliday:hover:before {
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    content: "";
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 $(function() {
   $(document).tooltip();
  });
```